# Inverse Fourier transform of 1/(1-1/4*e^(-jw))

Tags: fourier-analysis, inverse, fourier-transform, signal-processing

How can I calculate the inverse Fourier transform of the following $$\frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{4}e^{-jw}}$$

I have tried looking at the table of Fourier transforms but I can't find anything useful. Thanks for any tips in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The given expression can be written as a geometric series:
$$\frac{1}{1 - \frac{1}{4}e^{-i\omega}}
= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{4^n}e^{-i\omega n}$$
which looks like the [discrete-time Fourier transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete-time_Fourier_transform) of the sequence $(1/4^n)_{n=0}^{\infty}$.

Comment: How do we get from that geometric series to the sequence you describe?

Comment: For any complex number $z$ with $|z| < 1$, we have $$\frac{1}{1-z} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}z^n$$ In this case, $z = \frac{1}{4}e^{-i\omega}$. See [geometric series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Formula) for the derivation of this formula.

Comment: Then see the discrete-time Fourier transform page I linked in the answer. By definition, the discrete-time Fourier transform of a sequence $a_n$ is $\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}a_n e^{-i\omega n}$. Comparing this with the geometric series, we conclude that $$a_n = \begin{cases}1/4^n & \text{if }n \geq 0 \\ 0 & \text{if }n < 0 \\ \end{cases}$$

Comment: I understand thank you!